# Функция WhereIn laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется таблица:

```
filters_to_products
Структура:
id
category_id
product_id
filter_id
```

Имеется форма

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="array[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="array[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="array[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="array[]">
  <button>Filter</button>
</form>
```

P.S инпуты динамические.

Имеется контроллер:

```
    foreach($request->input('array') as $row) {  
      $ids = $row;
    }
    $items = Item::where('category_id', '1')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get()->all();
```

Беда в том, что фильтр должен отсеивать значения, к примеру если я выбрал `чекбокс с value 1 и чекбокс с value 2` то мне должны вывестись только те item-ы которые есть в таблице по совпадению, а тут получается что у меня выборка происходит по тем которые имеют такой id, то есть грубо говоря позиции не фильтруются, а суммируются на основе фильтров.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна функция where() ?
`Items::where(cpu, 'i7')->where(diagonal, 13)->where(category, 'Notebook')->get();`

UPD

Тогда так

```
 $items = Item::where('category_id', '1')
 foreach($request->input('array') as $row) {  
  $items->where('id', row)
 }
 $items->get();
```

Должно сработать на основе особенностей Eloquent-а, когда запрос не заканчивается, пока не выполнен `get()`. Ну или можно менее извращенно сделать через whereRaw, как больше нравится.

Comment: Почти, обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего, сразу сделать так:

```
$item = Item::where('category_id', '1')->whereIn('id', array_filter(request()->array))->get();
```